# Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using `tensorflow 2.4.1`

When I run my program, I'm getting this error and can't use my `gpu`.

I'm using `CUDA 11.0`, `cudnn 8.0`

```
2021-02-07 03:36:18.132005: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/models/kpş,i.py:5: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2021-02-07 03:36:19.735127: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-07 03:36:19.739052: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.715634: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.56GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 119.24GiB/s
2021-02-07 03:36:20.716281: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.723519: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.724040: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.729436: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.731800: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.741580: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.745576: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-02-07 03:36:20.746657: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-02-07 03:36:20.746971: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-07 03:36:20.836861: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-07 03:36:20.837144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-02-07 03:36:20.837314: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-02-07 03:36:20.837493: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that is running into this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think I can help you with providing a `cudnn64_8.dll` file (this is the download link: https://www.dll-files.com/cudnn64_8.dll.html). When you get the file, you can just put in your `bin` directory. For example, usually in windows platform, you can put it into `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin`.

Comment: I was a little bit suspicious of downloading this .dll file but it worked

Comment: It worked thanks. `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin`

Comment: Official URL https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn but you'll have to sign up for their developer program (which is just 2 clicks) so seemed ok 

Answer (score 24):

The missing dll file is located in the cuDNN folder. I was able to resolve the issue by copying the `cudnn64_8.dll` file to the CUDA folder, i.e., `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin`.

cuDNN is listed as a requirement for tensorflow to work and you can download it [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn). You need to register a developer account first though.

Comment: This one works, kinda a silly problem. Thanks

Comment: from the official nvidia documentation:
Copy the following files into the CUDA toolkit directory.
Copy <installpath>\cuda\bin\cudnn*.dll to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\vx.x\bin.
Copy <installpath>\cuda\include\cudnn*.h to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\vx.x\include.
Copy <installpath>\cuda\lib\x64\cudnn*.lib to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\vx.x\lib\x64.

Answer (score 9):

watch this [video](https://youtu.be/xQVOaTUm9lM) to solve this problem, 
this file not found error arises due to the missing of Microsoft visual studio C++ reproducible file in the CUDA folder. 
additional;
with the `PyTorch in conda environment`, there is no addition CUDA and Cudnn installation, because after type `conda install pytorch`, conda installs both CUDA and cudnn into that conda environment.

Comment: Going through this procedure, and the most important point is to avoid the default downloads of all six required packages and use instead the (possibly archived) versions noted in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue as well after following all of the installation instructions for CuDNN. The root cause of the problem is very simple. In the installation instructions, it tells you to add `<root>\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.x` to your `PATH`. At least for Tensorflow, this happens to be wrong. You need to add `<root>\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.x\bin` to your `PATH`. That should fix the problem. It did for me.

I see a couple answers talking about moving the `cudnn64_8.dll` file to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin`. The reason why this works is that CUDA automatically adds that bin directory to your `PATH` when you install it. So, moving the `cudnn64_8.dll` there effectively adds it to your `PATH`.

I'd rather keep things in their proper location so I like this way more.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share the steps that allowed me to solve all the issues like

- `Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found`
- `Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll.`
- `Could not load library cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll.`

1. First make sure that the driver for your NVIDIA GPU is installed. You can download the driver [here](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
2. Install the CUDA Toolkit that you can download [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).
3. Download the cudnn zip file from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) and unzip it.
4. From the unzipped cudnn, copy-paste the files in the `bin`, `include` and `lib` subdirectories to the corresponding `bin`, `include` and `lib` subdirectories located at `...\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.x`.
5. Download the Zlib archive from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows) and unzip it.
6. Copy-paste `zlibwapi.dll` from the Zlib archive to the `bin` subdirectory at `...\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.x`.

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled at this error as well and what I've figured is that cudnn requires a different installation. Here is a guide for the installation and the packages required https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn.
*edit -> in the link above you can download the cuddn version that tensorflow requires, then you will place them in the needed folders and that will fix your issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ironic that the only actually-correct answer has few votes, and people complaining because it doesn't include the three pages of installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The solution proposed in [this link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/missing-cudnn64-8-dll-file/198920) worked for me. They propose to install cuDNN and explain how to do so [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html)

For me personally, out of the explanation above all that was missing was ZLIB (or more specifically zlibwapi) which I installed via Anaconda.