# Python 3.8.8 Jupyter notebook kernel dies when I call model.fit() when I try to use my GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

My tensorflow recognizes my gpu

However, when I call model.fit() on my data it shows:

epoch(1/2) and then the kernel dies immediately

If I run this in a separate virtual environment with no GPU it works fine:

I have simplified the model architecture and number of training points to only ten as a quick test and it still fails

#### Simple example

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(Dense(4,
                activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.001)

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy' , optimizer = opt,   metrics = ['accuracy'] )

info = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=2,shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

versions:

Python 3.8.8
Num GPUs Available 1

2.5.0-dev20210227
2.4.3

cuda v11.2

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer my own question rather than deleting this because maybe someone else will be making the same simple mistake I was.

The main mistake I made was having the incorrect CUDA download. you can refer to the what versions are correct at this link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

TLDR: Just follow this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0

This also highlighted the importance of a virtual environment where you control the package versions to prevent incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I transferred the code into a python file and found the root cause. In my case it was copying cudnn dll files into `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin`. Check the following link as well:

[Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083545/could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudnn64-8-dll-dlerror-cudnn64-8-dll-not-found)